# Datatable for a child record asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a cshtml view to perform crud operations on a client record. In the same view i want a data table to perform crud operations on children of each client , so one client can have multiple children. I want to add edit those child records however only when the entire client record is saved then the child record should be updated or created , deleted etc. Can i know if jquery datatable is the best for this , and how will i save child in memory and perform save all at once...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Used javascript arrays, and hidden variables to make sure that added/edited data is not lost when posted back to controller .

Answer (score 0):

You can load load the datatable child using Ajax (on click event of the client table). Then read all rows from the datatable child to get the data that you need.

Comment: Yes, but how to persist child records temporarily, until the final save for client record is performed